# How to import a realm in Keycloak and exit

Tags: ansible, keycloak

I have followed the Keycloak admin guide to [export and import realms](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/export-import.html) using `standalone.sh` it does work but it starts the server and does not exit.

This is a problem for me because I want to automate this process via executing an Ansible playbook and so I can't because the task never ends.

I found a workaround in Ansible by using `async` and `wait_for` but was hoping for a better way that does not require using the Admin REST API.

```
- name: Stop keycloak
  service:
    name: keycloak
    state: stopped
- name: Import realm into Keycloak
  shell: "{{keycloak_home}}/bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=master -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=SAME_FILE -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=master"
  async: 30
  poll: 0
- name: Wait for Keycloak to be started and listen on port 8080
  wait_for:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8080
    delay: 10
- name: Restart keycloak
  service:
    name: keycloak
    state: restarted
```

Comment: You can use the admin console as well to import a realm. In that way, you wont have to rely on the standalone script at all. If you go to "Add Realm" section. It shows you an option to choose the file to create realm from.

Comment: Yes I know that but remember that my iniitial goal is to automate this process through ansible

Comment: We have exactly that scenario of managing Keylcoak with Ansible in a bigger deployment, but we use the Admin REST API to import the realm. Meaning we have a role that gets the access token and afterwards pushes the realm to keycloak. Works as expected and I think that's also the intended way to do it.

Comment: Interesting, is there any code you could share?

Comment: I don't know if thqt cqn help but ansible has a couple of keycloak modules https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/list_of_identity_modules.html

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with [Keycloak Admin CLI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#the-admin-cli).

Authenticate once before running any command (see section *Authenticating* on the link above), for example:

```
$ kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm demorealm --user admin --password admin
```

Commands for full export/import example (see section *Realm operations* > *Updating a realm*):

```
$ kcadm.sh get realms/demorealm > demorealm.json
$ vi demorealm.json
$ kcadm.sh update realms/demorealm -f demorealm.json
```

Can do partial export/import as well using commands like: `kcadm.sh create partial-export | partialImport ...`.

Comment: Did you just quote the documentation? It turns out that example does not work very well, i.e. realm updates don't work, clients do. Using 4.4.0 Final

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Do you get any error message you can share? Something different than expected? What did you try? On keycloak 4.4.0, works for me: I tried the `kcadm.sh get realms/demo > demorealm.json`, changed one of the demo realm settings (Access Token Lifespan) via console, then `kcadm.sh update realms/demo -f  demorealms` and got back the old value before change. So far, so good.

Comment: Well it turns out there a a number of fields that are not updated, it just so happened that the first 5 or so that I tried were ignored. It was very confusing. I found several tickets in the backlog for poor test coverage, and we have found several instances where the import and updates are not well documented and/or silently do nothing.

Comment: Of all the options we considered Keycloak was the best in terms of deployment and automated configurability, the documentation for the newer auth components is in need of a polish.

Comment: Import/export via API does not allow for all the same things as import/export on startup: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#admin-console-export-import